Why does KDE come with geoclue and gpsd running by default (which could be used for location tracking) and how to disable it?
Why are these things enabled by default on Debian12 with KDE (Plasma 5.27)?
Maybe it could be useful for a few users if it was installed but not enabled and not running by default and just an option one could enable in the configs or which could be enabled by the user through a prompt. If it's running by default this also means that after upgrades it could be running again. This is a privacy issue, an undesired bloat service, and a larger attack surface even if there was a proper and vulnerability-free permissions-management for GPS-location-access. So why is it enabled and running by default (links such as existing KDE discussions about this and explanations please).
Is this the correct best way to disable it (one may still have to check after every OS upgrade and this should also work for users who don't want to uninstall things if they use geoclue sometimes on demand):

sudo start-stop-daemon -T --name gpsd
sudo rm /etc/xdg/autostart/geoclue-demo-agent.desktop
sudo apt-get remove geoclue-2.0 (if not needed at all)

Issue about it is here.

Ask Debian/KDE developers, not here.

Asked about it here, maybe there will be some info in regards to the first question.

"The distribution is responsible for deciding what to ship by default and whether to enable these services."
